# Did the strangers take part in the holy convocation?

Tags: exodus

I'm reading Exodos 12 and in verse 19 says:

> For seven days no leaven shall be found in your houses, since whoever eats what is leavened, that same person shall be cut off from the congregation of Israel, whether **he is a stranger** or a native of the land.

Then the strangers take part in the feast of unleavened bread. My question is whether they used to take part in the holy convocations, registered in verse 16, or not?

Answer (score 1):

Ellicott comments as follows:

> (19) A stranger—i.e., a foreigner in blood, who has been adopted into
> the nation, received circumcision, and become a full proselyte. It is
> not improbable that many of the “six hundred thousand” reckoned to
> “Israel” (Exodus 12:37) were of this class—persons who had joined
> themselves to the nation during the sojourn in Egypt, or even earlier.
> (See Note on Genesis 17:13.) When the “exclusiveness” of the Hebrews
> is made a charge against them, justice requires us to remember that
> from the first it was open to those who were not of Hebrew blood to
> share in the Hebrew privileges by accepting the covenant of
> circumcision, and joining themselves to the nation. It was in this way
> that the Kenites. and even the Gibeonites, became reckoned to Israel.

Similarly, The Pulpit Commentary says this:

> Verse 19. - This is not a mere "vain repetition" of verse 15. It adds
> an important extension of the punitive clause - "that soul shall be
> cut off from Israel" - from Israelites proper to proselytes. We are
> thus reminded, at the very time when Israel is about to become a
> nation and to enter upon its inheritance of exclusive privileges, that
> no exclusion of the Gentiles by reason of race or descent was ever
> contemplated by God, either at the giving of the law, or at any other
> time. In Abraham all the families of them were to be blessed (Genesis
> 12:3). It was always open to any Gentiles to join themselves to Israel
> by becoming "proselytes of justice," adopting circumcision and the
> general observance of the law, and joining the Israelite community.
> The whole law is full of references to persons of this class (Exodus
> 20:10; Exodus 23:12; Leviticus 16:29; Leviticus 17:10; Leviticus
> 18:26; Leviticus 20:2; Leviticus 24:16; Numbers 35:15; Deuteronomy
> 5:14; Deuteronomy 16:11-14; Deuteronomy 24:17, 19; Deuteronomy 27:19;
> Deuteronomy 29:11, etc.). It must have been largely recruited in the
> times immediately following the exodus from the "mixed multitude"
> which accompanied the Israelites out of Egypt (Exodus 12:38), and from
> the Kenites who joined them in the wilderness (Numbers 10:29-31;
> Judges 1:16). Born in the land - i.e., an Israelite by birth - "the
> land" is, no doubt, Canaan, which is regarded as the true "Land of
> Israel" from the time when it was assigned by God to the posterity of
> Abraham (Genesis 15:18). Exodus 12:19.

Indeed, simple mathematics supports this idea.  In the four generations (Gen 15:16) from Joseph to Moses, it would be impossible for the Israelite men to have expanded from 75 people to more than 600,000 without the help of foreign women and men, mostly from Egypt, such as the mixed multitude.